# TemplateSyntaxError in django python

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm getting an error message stating

```
Invalid block tag on line 81: 'ifequal'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

Here is the corresponding code snippet:

```
{% ifequal request.session.role 'cust' %}
    <li class="nav-item active m1-3">
        <a class="nav-link" href="giveadd">Give Advertisement</a>
    </li>
{% endifequal %}
```

The issue arises at the 'ifequal' block tag, and the reason for this error is currently unclear to me.

Answer (score 1):

The tag is invalid probably because you are using a version of **Django >= 4.0**, when the `{% ifequal %}` and the `{% ifnotequal %}` template tags have been removed.

Look at the Django official [release note](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/4.0/#features-removed-in-4-0).